# Clearing HTML 5 offline cache programatically

Tags: javascript, html, caching, offline-caching

**Is it possible to stop and clear the offline cache (HTML 5) programatically?**

---

Explanation:

I've got a working **offline web app**. That web app is **updated frequently** (changing the manifest), causing the browser to **request the page from the server again**. Now under some conditions (e.g. internal errors) **the website may send an error page** instead of the actual page **under the same URL**. This is something **i can not prevent**. But in that case, i want the brower to **stop caching**, so the error page is not getting cached and thus not being loaded everytime the user tries to access the URL (since the page might work again already)

I am using C# (ASP.NET) and JS for that website.

Comment: If your page can be differ between requests, for whatever reason, you'd be better off not having it in the cache at all.  Is there any way you can serve a static HTML page instead and load the data from the unreliable page via AJAX?  You could then detect the `500` errors.

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately too easy to manipulate as the errors can even be security related

Comment: Security errors should give you a different response code (eg `401` or `403`).  Either way, the only way you're going to be able to do anything about failed HTTP responses on the client side is to initiate the requests with JavaScript.

Comment: There are no failed HTTP responses or error codes, it's a custom error page that will be sent instead of the expected one. And i want that one to be displayed regularily. All i want is to "turn off" the offline cache when that happens.

Comment: If your error page isn't returning HTTP error codes then you're doing it wrong.  AppCache is built on top of HTTP, you have to get the HTTP parts right to make it work properly.  Note that [the specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#downloading-or-updating-an-application-cache) requires the browser abort the cache process if "the server returns a 4xx or 5xx response or equivalent" for an explicit or fallback entry in the manifest.

Comment: Unfortunately "abort" just means stopping the update of the cache, not removing it. I just tested it: when an error is produced serverside while the client tries to retrieve the HTML file from the server in order to update the cache, it just loads the same page again (chromes console says "OK - from cache"). As soon as i manually remove the cache from chrome and reload the page, the error page is displayed (proof that it was there all the time but wasn't displayed)